# THREE.JS Raycasting with an entire line

Tags: three.js, computational-geometry

I have a geometry and a `line3`. The `line3` is "hovering" a slight bit above the surface of the geometry, and I want to find the faces that would be touching the `line3` if it was to be brought down and wrapped on to the surface.

Of course because I cannot "wrap" my `line3`, I am raycasting the points of the `line3` on to the geometry, and finding the intersecting points.

This allows me to detect face 1 and face 4, but I fail to detect face 2 and 3 because there is no point on the `line3` to raycast from, other than its starting and ending points.

[image]

How can I come up with an algorithm that allows me to detect all the faces that the `line3` would "cut across" the surface, if wrapped on to it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to wrap a rope around a cube and find all triangles the rope touches? This sounds like shortest path problem on surface. You can do it on a cube by flattening it into 2D and cast 3 straight lines (and find the shortest) if they are on neighboring surfaces, or cast 12 lines if they are on opposite surfaces. [See this post for details.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023721/finding-the-shortest-path-between-two-points-on-the-surface-of-a-cube) There are no easy solutions on finding geodesic lines going across arbitrary meshes. You may find a relatively good solution based on [geodesic line alongside mesh edges](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/index.html)

If you don't care whether the path is the shortest or not, and just want to "cast a shadow" on the surface, then the solution depends on which direction your "light source" is. Create an infinitely long triangle with your line segment and "direction of light", and test all triangles in the mesh to see if they intersect with this triangle.